# Exception while instantiating EJBContainer

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am new to EJB.

I am creating a simple Maven web application using NetBeans 7.3.1 and version of Glassfish server used is 3.1.2

I am implementing JUnit test cases for Session Beans and I followed this link for jUnit integration: https://netbeans.org/kb/73/javaee/maven-entapp-testing.html

I followed every step described there but I'm getting exception while instantiating EJBContainer.

```
EJBContainer container = javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
SEVERE: EJB6001:Caught exception instantiating EmbeddedContainer.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.hk2.component.MultiMap.<init>(Z)V
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.<init>(Habitat.java:127)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.<init>(Habitat.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newHabitat(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createHabitat(Main.java:444)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.StaticGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(StaticGlassFishRuntime.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at com.javaee.maven.test.services.LoginServiceTest.testDoLogout(LoginServiceTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 44.258 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDoLogout(com.javaee.maven.test.services.LoginServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 44.136 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jvnet.hk2.component.MultiMap.<init>(Z)V
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:142)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at com.javaee.maven.test.services.LoginServiceTest.testDoLogout(LoginServiceTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I get this same error attempting to execute an Arquillian unit test using embedded glassfish

Answer (score -1):

When testing EJBs, you need to distinguish 2 cases:

- **Unit test**: You want to test the logic within the EJB. In that case, you write a unit test case (e.g. with JUnit) and mock out all external references needed in the test, e.g. everything which would normally be injected from the container. For that, you can use mocking frameworks such as [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).
- **Integration test**: You want to test the EJB and its surroundings and you need container services such as injection or a datasource. In that case, you can use an EmbeddedContainer, but it is often cumbersome to do so, plus, you don't have the real behavior of your container. That's why it's advisable, to use Frameworks such as [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), which allow for run your usual JUnit test within an embedded or real container.